# Infrastructure Wireless Network Without Router

Tags: router, wifi, infrastructure

Is there any way to create an infrastructure wireless network without a router? In other words, is there some way to make a PC behave as a wireless router? Other PCs should be able to see this network as an access point network, not as an Ad-hoc one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [HostAP](http://hostap.epitest.fi/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

As Peter suggested, look at HostAP. However, it requires a wifi card with specific capabilities. The wifi card needs to be able to run in **Master** mode, not just infrastructure/ad-hoc modes. Also, you will need to run some flavour of Linux on it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a WAP. Not all WAP's are also routers. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: I need to use a PC, cause I need to install custom DHCP servers, DNS servers, etc. I'm not sure I can do all that on a WAP (i'm assuming you are talking about wireless access points).

Comment: What do you mean "custom" DHCP and DNS servers? Do you mean that you already have DHCP\DNS servers and need the wireless clients to use those? If so, that's how WAP's work. Can you imagine how hard it would have been to get wireless networks in the enterprise if companies couldn't use their existing DHCP\DNS infrastructure? Wireless would have never made it off of the drawing board.

Comment: Hmmm...you've got me thinking...I'm actually wondering why I'm not using a WAP...I thought I had a good reason, but I can't remember now :D